# Azure DevOPS - Get notified when you are assigned a work item

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am currently struggling with my Azure DevOPS project where I would like that every user of the project to receive an email notification whenever a work item (task/user story/bug) is:

1. Assigned to that person
2. Re-assigned to other person
3. Some properties have been changed inside the work item

Therefore, I [have followed the Microsoft docs regarding this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/about-notifications?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511) and I could not manage to receive any of the notifications mentioned in the list above.

What I have done:

- Added users to the Default Project Team
- Went to Project Settings -> Notifications and created the following Subscription

[image: snip of the subscription config]

- Checked that the entire Organization has the personal notification "A work item assigned" for any project inside the organization is active (and it is)

[image: snip of the sub]

Even though all the members of the project team has the same settings as presented above, none of us are receiving any email (not even the ones regarding "A work item is assigned" - even though the setting is on the entire organization)

What should I check further?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your help!
I have found the issue.

For some reason, we had to RE-confirm the email address for "Contact email" via each invidivdual profile.

There's still one issue left: we are now receiving assignment notifications for each User Story BUT not for assignments for Tasks.

E.g. i assign a task to a user, he does not receive notification
i assign a user story to a user, he DOES receive notification

Any idea what should i check further?

Answer (score 0):

Check `Delivery settings` to see whether `Deliver to individual members` is selected.

[image]

[image]

And try to uncheck `Skip initiator` checkbox:

[image]